# Run cmd command in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I am trying to run cmd command in windows application in C#. My code is,

```
    progressBar1.Show();
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo; 
    Process Process;

    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
        int percent = (int)(((double)progressBar1.Value/(double)progressBar1.Maximum) * 100);
        progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial",(float)7.02,FontStyle.Regular),Brushes.Black, new Point(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 -7));

        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
        ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);                    

        Process.Close();                    
    }
    progressBar1.Hide();
```

Problem is, if I run the command in command promt; it installs the driver in couple of second but if I run the command in C# it doesn't work.

Can anyone explain me, is there any code I am missing or not?

command is

```
ExecuteCommand("\"C:\\Disk1.Win7\\setup.exe\" /s /f1\"C:\\Disk1.Win7\\setup_install.iss\" /a\"C:\\Disk1.Win7\\OposData.reg\"");
```

Comment: Aren't you calling Process.Start 300000 times?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen "well there's your problem right there".

Comment: Each time the process is only alive for **3ms** before being killed!

Comment: I am calling Process.Start just to show what is the progress of installation. Even though, if I am not using progress bar it works in same manner. After waiting for 15 min if I closed the application then it just install the driver in a second but it doesn't install the driver when I run the application.

Comment: You want to cook an egg, but you "switch on the stove and turn it off" for 300000 times in 15 minutes.

Comment: if you want to show a fake progress bar use a timer or Thread.Sleep(1000); something like this, but for sure you should remove from the loop code that are starting driver installation.

Comment: Calling `CreateGraphics` usually indicate a huge design mistake in your code.

Comment: @leppie : it did work if I remove progress bar. But what if I want to show in application how much progress or how much percent is complete?

Comment: @GregC , I think you're misinterpreting his question; just as your previous "answer" entailed, he is not asking multiple questions, he asking why his code doesn't work.  Like any other question, there can be many more answers and questions created from a single one without his intention.  We have narrowed it down into the fact that he calls the "command" 300000 times within one "for" statement.  His code runs quickly, when run manually, but fails when run from C#.
Try moving your command statement around, and consider some other loop, like WHILE, while installing the driver.

Comment: @plast1K Sounds like AlvinWong has the correct idea then.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving the code for running your COMAMND,

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
    ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);                    

    Process.Close();
```

Outside of that "for" loop.  Adding a WHILE loop which runs the driver installer, with the for loop embedded within it.

This may solve your problem.  You're on the right track, just consider aligning things a little differently.  As Alvin and a few others stated, your COMMAND is only being processed for 3ms, before it is shut down, and started again; to a maximum of 300000 times.  Things just need to be moved around.

Answer (score 0):

Start small by writing a program that launches this command once, then does not close it, but sits there waiting for user input.

After this works, consider using something similar to a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to add responsiveness and structure to your code.  You could use [HasExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) property to monitor lifetime of your process.

Then consider using FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes to specify arguments instead of hard-coding paths and file names.